# clang on Windows - incorrect header file path

Tags: path, clang, header-files

I built clang using VS2013 and then ran it from the command line with a -v option (clang -v testfile.c).  Among the things it reported was:

#include <...> search starts here:

C:\Program Files (stand-alone)\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.7.0\include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include

I don't understand why it is even looking at the Microsoft headers in the first place. I do not have an environment variable named INCLUDE. I verified this by doing "set INCLUDE" from the command line getting a message saying there was no such environment variable.  So, where and why is clang getting this information and how do I stop it?  During the compile several warnings (not errors) occur regarding some of the things in Microsoft header files too.

The version it reports is:

clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target i686-pc-windows-msvc

I understand the i686-pc-windows part, but why the msvc part?  If that means it was built with msvc then that makes sense, but if it means that clang was built to run with msvc support, I don't understand why.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, please be a bit more specific. What target do you want to compile for, MinGW?! Or what's wrong with the MS include path?

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the usage of clang.  The target I want to compile arbitrary C code for is Windows 8.1 64-bit.  My original impression was that once I built clang using Visual Studio 2013, which I successfully did, I would not need anything but clang itself and the various header files and libraries that come with it in order to build some simple C programs that would run on Windows 8.1.  From what you asked above, however, I get the impression that clang is not a complete product and Visual Studio, MinGW, or something similar is necessary when using it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, clang does not come with a C library.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  It was obviously my misunderstanding, but it all makes sense now.